# "{0} wants to display a new window" when using displayDialogAsync

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I'm using Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync and when I launch our app in Outlook task pane I get a dialog with the message "Test wants to display a new window". The word Test is a ShortString that comes from our Manifest file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzqVo.jpg

But when I click the Outlook On Send feature I get the same dialog but with the text "{0} wants to display a new window". The string doesnt seem to be pulled from the Manifest file that we use.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DCde.jpg

I tried adding a label string to the send hook but it doesnt follow the add-in schema. Why does {0} appear and how can I replace that with a string?

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
    <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="sendTest" />
</ExtensionPoint>
```

This is the string that I use and is shown on the dialog when I dont click send

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="buttonLabel" DefaultValue="Test"/>
</bt:ShortStrings>
```

Complete Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
      xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
      xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>1111111</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Sample</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="myApp" />
  <Description DefaultValue="some text"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="img" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="img" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="url" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>url</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>url</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="img"/>
        <RequestedHeight>60</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="img" />
        <RequestedHeight>60</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="img" />
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="img" />
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="ReadOrEdit"  />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasAttachment" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="green" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                            <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="initOnSend" />
                        </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- Defines Taskpane in Read mode -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="black" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="blue" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="yellow" />
                      <Description resid="red" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">

                <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                  <Label resid="black" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="blue" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="yellow" />
                      <Description resid="red" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="composeTaskPaneUrl" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>

              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon-16" DefaultValue="img"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon-32" DefaultValue="img"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon-80" DefaultValue="img"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="composeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="img"/>
          <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="img"/>
          <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="img" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="black" DefaultValue="sample"/>
          <bt:String id="blue" DefaultValue="Test"/>
          <bt:String id="yellow" DefaultValue="sample"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="red" DefaultValue="some text"/>
          <bt:String id="green" DefaultValue="some text"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```